# Clear selected list item (so there's no selected list item) in Python/PySide

Tags: python, pyside, qt-designer

I have an application written in Python using PySide, the UI was created with QT Designer.

I have a list in the window, which has a set of items.  When the application loads, it seems to grab the last item in the list (even though there is no 'highlighted' row showing in the list).  If I break and check if there is a selected item at that time, I will get the last item in the list.

I have this code:

```
    @QtCore.Slot(QTreeWidgetItem,QTreeWidgetItem)
    def on_list_currentItemChanged(self,current=None,previous=None):
        if current:
            self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(True)
        else:
            self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(False)
```

Which determines if there is a current item selected.  So upon initial load, I expect current to be empty, but it's not, it's pointing to the last item in the list, even though no item has been selected.

Is there something that I'm missing?  Or, alternatively, how do I tell the list to not have a selected row/deselect all rows?

Ultimately what I'm looking for is (a) that when the form loads and the list is originally shown with no selected item, that the delete button is disabled and even (b) if someone should delete an item through this action, there won't be a selected item after that (so they couldn't just hit delete twice and delete two rows in sequence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current item and the selection are not necessarily the same thing. The current item refers to the item with the keyboard focus; the selection refers to the currently highlighted items. So a tree widget with no selection will still have a current item (unless it has no items at all).

So one solution might be to simply check that the current item is also selected:

```
@QtCore.Slot(QTreeWidgetItem, QTreeWidgetItem)
def on_list_currentItemChanged(self, current=None, previous=None):
    if current is not None and current.isSelected():
        self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(False)
```

**EDIT**

After taking a look at the Qt source code, it appears the above code won't work because the `currentItemChanged` signal is emitted before the selection is reset.

So, instead, I would suggest using the `itemSelectionChanged` signal, and checking the `selectedItems`:

```
def on_list_ItemSelectionChanged(self):
    if self.list.selectedItems():
        self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.ui.actionDelete_Task.setEnabled(False)
```

NB: taking this approach may also entail replacing the usage of `currentItem()` with `selectedItems()[0]` elsewhere in your code.

Comment: I think the idea of your answer is what I'm looking for, so I'm accepting.  Any idea though why it's acting like a "currentItemChanging" event instead of "Changed" event?  When it fires in my code, the row I clicked on is the "current", but current.isSelected() is False.  previous.isSelected() is True though.  I can click different rows and it's always the same, previous.isSelected() is True, but not current.

Comment: @Mike. I have updated my answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I think I was just using the wrong signal.  In this case, when clicking the first row after having none selected, selectedItems() still returned 0, as if this fired before the row was "selected".  Subsequent row changes showed selectedItems() having a value.  I changed the signal to itemSelectionChanged and now it's up and running as expected.  When this fires, selectedItems() represents what I would expect it to.  Thanks alot for your help!